# Gwt Bootstrap add Image to dropdown menu not submenu

Tags: gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I have to display image instead of text in bootstrap drop down menu (not in sub menu). I don't know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me in achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

you do like so :

Exemple :

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img src="http://www.goodfellasmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Most-famous-lol-face.jpg" alt="">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
   your texte here :  
  </ul>
</div>
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9795/)